# Mi servidor no se conecta a la base de datos y tampoco envía el correo de los que se registran

Tags: php, html

1. Este es el registro de usuarios en html:

```html
<!--Registro-->
        <form  id="registro" action="EnlaceQrBD.php"  method="post">
        <h2>Regístrarme</h2>
       <input type="number" id="cedula " name="cedula" maxlength="8" required placeholder="Cédula 
         de 
        Identidad">
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required placeholder="Nombre y Apellido">
         <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="Correo Electronico">
        <input type="text" id="motivo " name="motivo" maxlength="50"  required placeholder="Por 
        que quieres ser vendedor">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id"><br><br>  
        <center><button type="submit">Enviar Registro</button></center>
        </form>
```

2. Aquí la conexión con la base de datos que también me genera un código qr para identificar a cada vendedor. Los datos se deben enviar al correo de la persona que se registra y a la institución:

```
<?php
         $host = 'localhost';
         $db   = 'u838300018_ecomerce';
         $user = 'root';
         $pass = '';
         $charset = 'utf8mb4';

         //creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
         $conexion = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, "" ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al 
         servidor de Base de datos");

        // Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
         $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $db ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha 
        podido conectar a la base de datos" );
        // establecer y realizar consulta. guardamos en variable.
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM alumnos";
         $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la 
        consulta a la base de datos");

        // Recoger los datos del formulario
        $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
         $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $motivo = $_POST['motivo'];

        // Insertar los datos en la base de datos
         $sql = "INSERT INTO vendedor (Cedula, Nombre, Email, Motivo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
         $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->execute([$cedula, $nombre, $email, $motivo]);

         // Generar código QR
          $datos_usuario = "Cédula: $cedula\nNombre: $nombre\nCorreo: $email\nMotivo: $motivo";
          $codigo_qr = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=" . 
          urlencode($datos_usuario);

          // Enviar correo electrónico
           $to = $email;
           $subject = "Registro como vendedor";
            $message = "¡Bienvenido! Ya eres un vendedor de centro de Importación.\nTus 
            datos:\n\nCédula: $cedula\nNombre: $nombre\nCorreo: $email\nMotivo: $motivo\n\nCódigo 
            QR: $codigo_qr";
            $headers = "From: vendedoresregistros@gmail.com";

           mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

         // Enviar correo electrónico a la institución
         $to_institucion = "vendedoresregistros@gmail.com";
         $subject_institucion = "Nuevo Registro como Vendedor";
         $message_institucion = "Se ha registrado un nuevo vendedor con los siguientes 
          datos:\n\nCédula: $cedula\nNombre: $nombre\nCorreo: $email\nMotivo: $motivo\n\nCódigo 
          QR: $codigo_qr";
         $headers_institucion = "From: vendedoresregistros@gmail.com";

         mail($to_institucion, $subject_institucion, $message_institucion, $headers_institucion);


          echo "¡Registrado exitosamente! Se ha enviado un correo electrónico con tus datos y el 
          código QR.";

          ?>
```

3. Una vez que introduzco los datos y presiono registrar me redirecciona a una ventana donde me muestra el código php, solo el código, y no realiza ninguna acción, tampoco me muestra una ventana de registro exitoso.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Qué error da cuando se intenta conectar a la base de datos?

Comment: Parece que mezclas código `mysqli` y `pdo`. Son dos herramientas distintas para interactuar con la BD.

Comment: te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: La función mail() no envía correos si colocas un campo 'From' que no pertenezca al su dominio. Por eso al colocar 'From: ...@gmail' no sale tu correo

Comment: Si solo le muestra el código PHP, no será también un problema de server?? Además dice: "Este es el registro de usuarios en HTML", cuando lo ideal fuera que ese registro aun con solo código HTML fuera un archivo PHP y no un .html